# Selecting a single radio button within SandRibbon

Tags: c#, xaml

We're currently using [SandRibbon](http://www.divelements.co.uk/net/controls/sandribbon/)  to emulate the Microsoft Office 2007 ribbon interface. We're using MVVM with our application.

An example:

XAML:

```
<SandRibbon:RibbonTab Text="TestTab">

    <SandRibbon:RibbonGroup Header="TestHeader"> 

        <SandRibbon:Button AutoCheck="Radio"
                           Command="{Binding GoToPageOne}"
                           IsChecked="{Binding ButtonOneIsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                           Text="Button One">

        <SandRibbon:Button AutoCheck="Radio"
                           Command="{Binding GoToPageTwo}"
                           IsChecked="{Binding ButtonTwoIsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                           Text="Button Two">

        <SandRibbon:Button AutoCheck="Radio"
                           Command="{Binding GoToPageThree}"
                           IsChecked="{Binding ButtonThreeIsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                           Text="Button Three">

    </SandRibbon:RibbonGroup>

</SandRibbon:RibbonTab>
```

The issue that I'm having is that despite navigating away, the previous button that you've selected is still highlighted and you'll have to hover over the button to remove the highlight.

I was wondering if there's a way for you to group these buttons so that only one would have their IsChecked property set to true?